# Trying to initialize PWM on PB4 on the TM4C123 Microcontroller

Tags: c, keil, pwm

As the tittle states I am trying to initialize PWM for PB4 on the TM4C123 microcontroller using Keil as the IDE. So far I have been able to initialize PB6 and PB7 but i'm not sure why PB4 isn't working. Do you guys know whats I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help. I have posted my working code for initalizing port B6 and the one that isnt working for port B4.

```
// PWM clock rate = processor clock rate/SYSCTL_RCC_PWMDIV
//                = BusClock/16
//                = 80 MHz/16 = 5 MHz 
// Output on PB7/M0PWM1
void PWM0B4_Init(uint16_t period, uint16_t duty) 
{
    
    volatile unsigned long delay;
    SYSCTL_RCGCPWM_R |= 0x01;             // 1) activate PWM0
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |= 0x02;            // 2) activate port B
    // delay = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R;         // allow time to finish activating
    while((SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R&0x02) == 0){};
    GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL_R |= 0x10;           // enable alt funct on PB4
    GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R &= ~0x000F000;      // configure PB4 as M0PWM2
    GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R |= 0x0004000;
    GPIO_PORTB_AMSEL_R &= ~0x10;          // disable analog functionality on PB4
    GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R |= 0x10;             // enable digital I/O on PB4 ** double check **
    SYSCTL_RCC_R = 0x00100000 |           // 3) use PWM divider
   (SYSCTL_RCC_R & (~0x000C0000));        //    configure for /16 divider
    
    PWM0_1_CTL_R = 0;                     // 4) re-loading down-counting mode
    PWM0_1_GENB_R = (PWM_1_GENB_ACTCMPBD_ONE|PWM_1_GENB_ACTLOAD_ZERO);

    // PB4 goes low on LOAD
    // PB4 goes high on CMPB down
    PWM0_1_LOAD_R = period - 1;           // 5) cycles needed to count down to 0
    PWM0_1_CMPB_R = duty - 1;             // 6) count value when output rises
    PWM0_1_CTL_R |= 0x00000001;           // 7) start PWM0
    PWM0_ENABLE_R |= 0x00000004;          // enable PB4/M0PWM2 **** check

}

// change duty cycle of PB4
// duty is number of PWM clock cycles output is high  (2<=duty<=period-1)
void PWM0B4_Duty(uint16_t duty)
{
    
    PWM0_1_CMPB_R = duty - 1;             // 6) count value when output rises
}




void PWM0B6_Init(uint16_t period, uint16_t duty)
{

  SYSCTL_RCGCPWM_R |=0x01;                  // 1) activate PWM0 
  SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R|=0x02;                  // 2) activate portB
  while ((SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R&0x02) == 0) {};           
  GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL_R |= 0x40;               // enable alt funct on PB6
  GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R &= ~0x0F000000;         // configure PB6 as PWM0
  GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R |= 0x04000000;              
  GPIO_PORTB_AMSEL_R &= ~0x40;              // disable analog functionality on PB6
  GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R |= 0x40;                 // enable digital I/O on PB6
  SYSCTL_RCC_R = 0x00100000 |               // 3) use PWM divider
  (SYSCTL_RCC_R & (~0x000C0000));            // configure for /16 divider to C
  PWM0_0_CTL_R = 0;                         // 4) re-loading down-counting mode
  PWM0_0_GENA_R = 0xC8;                     // low on LOAD, high on CMPA down
  // PB6 goes low on LOAD
  // PB6 goes high on CMPA down
  PWM0_0_LOAD_R = period - 1;               // 5) cycles needed to count down to 0
  PWM0_0_CMPA_R = duty - 1;                 // 6) count value when output rises
  PWM0_0_CTL_R |= 0x00000001;               // 7) start PWM0
  PWM0_ENABLE_R |= 0x00000001;              // enable PB6/M0PWM0

}

// change duty cycle of PB6
// duty is number of PWM clock cycles output is high (2<=duty<=period-1)
void PWM0B6_Duty(uint16_t duty)
{

  PWM0_0_CMPA_R = duty - 1; // 6) count value when output rises

}
```

Comment: Sorry thats how we've always formatted in school, what should I change to make it more readable here?

Comment: Oh ok gotcha let me fix, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `PWM0_1*` is correct? As far as i understand the datasheet it says PB4 uses Module 0 PWM 2. (Should it not be `PWM0_2*`?)

Comment: I initially had it to PWM0_2 but in the data sheet it also says PB4 is controlled by module 0 PWM generator 1. Thats why I went with PWM0_1

Comment: Can you post the working code for PB6 or PB7? I do not know the µC you are using. Are you sure that enabling digital IO mode does not disable the alt function? Maybe set digital IO and disable analog before you enable the alt function?

Comment: Ive posted the working code for port B6. Sorry it took long had to complete another project over the weekedn

Comment: I think you are off by 4 bit (one hexadecimal digit) when you set `GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R` (both times). Should it not be `~0x000F0000` and `0x00040000` ?

Comment: I do not know where your problem is, but here are some suggestions: Write it as similar to `PWM0B6_Init` as possible, so you can use diff/vimdiff to compare them. Use the same order as in the datasheet in the example under 20.4.

Comment: Some things i notice: Do you set PWM0 of RCGC0? Do you set GPIOB of RCGC2? Do you set USEPWMDIV in RCC? You set `PWM0_1_GENB_R` but datasheet says PWMENABLE - PWM2EN uses pwm1A (B vs A). Hope you find out what is wrong.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Thank you so much for your help its been breaking my had all week. Ill definitely check those things out after class today, if i get it working ill post an update. Thanks again though, much appreciated.